# Contact list disappears from Included List in ECM Recipient Tab

Tags: list-manager, ecm

I am running into a wired issue with Include List while creating a campaign

- I create contact list and segmented list and then try to create a
  campaign. When in the Recipients tab in campaign builder I can see
  the contact list and all segmented list in the Include List drop
  down. I can add and remove and add the lists back as many times as I
  want without any issues or they getting disappeared from the drop
  down.
- Now when I come back the next day and I open up a draft campaign and
  go to the Recipient tab,  I do see the lists I had selected yesterday
  but now when I remove the list and try to add it back I do not see it
  again in the drop down. Also If I create a new campaign I do not see
  any list in the drop down
- If I go to Sitecore and make any changes to the list (the change can
  be as simple as adding a space to the list name) from
  /sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Contact Lists/... and just
  save the list and  go  back to the Email Campaign and log back in and
  go to the Recipient tab I can see the list I just changed in the drop
  down and I can add and remove and add them back as many times as I
  want without any issues or they getting disappeared.

Seems like there is some indexing issue when I make a change and save  the list is appears again in the drop down. Not sure why it gets removed from index after a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sitecore bug. Sitecore first gets all the list from the sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master index and then shows only the top 10 List and then filters them based on the logged in user.
That is why when a list is removed and then added again, it gets added at the last of the index and therefore never shows in the top 10 results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're referring to the initial dropdown list on the recipients tab of EXM.
[image]

I regularly see an incomplete lists of lists in that dropdown.  I get around that problem by selecting the 'add existing list' option.  That typically provides a more comprehensive list of lists.  It also includes a search function, so you can search for the specific list.
[image]

I think the condition that you referenced is a SPEAK bug in Sitecore, as it shows up in other areas of the application.

Comment: this is a sitecore bug. It seems like sitecore gets all the list from the sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master index and then shows only the top 10 and probably then filters them based on the logged in user.

That is why when a remove a list it get removed and added to the last of the index and never makes it back to the top 10 results.

I am trying to write my own custom code now because we do not want to give user the access to add from existing list because we want the lists to appear based on logged in user roles and not on read access